# Shopify Variant Price Now Showing Correctly

Tags: shopify, variant

This seems like it so be such a simple one but for whatever reason I can't see the forest for trees. So I have the current situation in Screenshot 1 where I have set three different variants for a product. The products are size based as ML...but for some reason all 3 variants are showing on the button instead of the one thats selected.

[image: Button Face]

The code I use to pull this out currently is:

```html
{% if current_variant.available %}
    <button type="submit" name="add" class="border--none">
        <span class="display--block padding--1 palette--background-color--green palette--color--white text-transform--uppercase letter-spacing--2px font-size--15px palette--color--white">
            add to bag &nbsp; | &nbsp; 

        <strong>
          {% for variant in product.variants %}

            {{ variant.price | money_without_trailing_zeros }}

          {% endfor %}


          </strong>

      </span>

    </button>
{% else %}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible with Liquid only. Liquid is just a templating language that is rendered at server side. It does not update on client side.

You want to display the price in button only for the selected variant, but Liquid has no information about that on server side and you just loop through the prices of all available variants. Hence, you see all prices in your button.

To fix this, use the first available or selected variant price using Liquid and update rest using JavaScript at client-side.

> Returns the variant object of the currently-selected variant if there
>   is a valid ?variant= query parameter in the URL. If there is no
>   selected variant, the first available variant is returned.

Doing so, your code will be like

```
  <button type="submit" name="add" class="border--none">
    <span class="display--block padding--1 palette--background-color--green palette--color--white text-transform--uppercase letter-spacing--2px font-size--15px palette--color--white">
      add to bag &nbsp; | &nbsp; 
      <strong>
        {{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.price | money_without_trailing_zeros }}
      </strong>
    </span>
  </button>
```

Then change price via JavaScript on variant change, that is dependent on your theme.

More information on [Selected or First Available Variant](https://shopify.dev/docs/liquid/reference/objects/product#product-selected_or_first_available_variant)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Bilal Akbar some more direction would be good for this/

Comment: @GlenWheeler as mentioned in the answer, it depends on the theme. Listen for the variant change event and then modify the button text.